# accessing javascript object within xul

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I have a series of javascript objects that I would like to make accessible from a xul page. I have looked at the XUL school tutorial on this and am getting nowhere.

Basically, I am writing a firefox extension that opens up a .xul page in a new tabbed window. My objects are initialized with certain data and I then want to be able to take in, validate, and store user information into javascript objects. Data doesn't have to be persistent. I.e. when the page closes, it goes away.

I already have my javascript objects coded up in a separate .js file, but I can't find any good, simple tutorial on how to access them from within the xul file.

Any help you all could give would be appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with including that file via usual `<script>` tag?

Comment: Well, the one major issue I am having right now is that I am unable to even do a simple document.write() to see what my data looks like. I get "TypeError: document.write is not a function" and I am rather a novice at this kinda stuff and am unsure how to fix this.

Comment: That's not really surprising given that XUL documents don't support `document.write()` (actually, no XML documents do and using `document.write()` is a bad idea even when dealing with HTML). How about using proper DOM functions or [Components.utils.reportError()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.reportError) for your debugging output?

Answer (score 0):

You can load the js file using this code:

```
Components.utils.import( 'resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm' );
Services.scriptloader.loadSubScript( YOUR_JS_FILE );
```

This is a like appending a  tag in your document but in a more cleaner way.